# implementing a helper function

Tags: scheme, helper, predicate

The procedure find-last takes a predicate of 1 argument and a list and returns the rightmost element in the list that satisfies the predicate. If no such element exists, return #f

```
(define (find-last-helper ans)
  (if (predicate? ans)
      (add1 ans)))
(define find-last
  (lambda (predicate? ls)
    (cond 
      [(null? ls) #f]
       [(equal? predicate? (car ls)) car ls]
        [else(find-last-helper(find-last ls(cdr ls)))])))
```

Am I missing something in the helper or find-last procedure?
It returns a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

**predicate?** is not visible to **find-last-helper**.  The way to fix that would be to move the definition of **find-last-helper** inside **find-last**'s lambda block or to add an extra parameter to **find-last-helper** so that **predicate?** can be passed to it.

I would recommend the former; assuming (from the name) that **find-last-helper** is only useful to **find-last**, it keeps the outer environment cleaner.

Note: assuming you fix the errors but keep the basic structure, your function is going to return the leftmost match - the first match it finds - rather than the rightmost.  To see this clearly, assume that the leftmost item in the list satisfies the predicate and step through your code; it should be clear that the third, recursive **cond** line is not executed.

Comment: I see, and I understand that. I tried that solution, but for whatever reason the code still doesnt work. Should I try re-writing it? It returns an incorrect argument count, now.

Comment: Not knowing how you re-edited the code, hard to say.  Another question, though: are you sure '(equal? predicate? (car ls))' is right?  Since **predicate** is a function, don't you mean '(predicate? (car ls))'?